# IBM Cloud DevOps java build + test

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, continuous-delivery

We have a pipeline that uses Build task with 'Gradle (Artifactory, Nexus, or SonarQube)' for gradle builds of java application. Tests are also using gradle, what tester type should be used for a pipeline job with that ?

Comment: Apparently, you can use the vanilla 'Test' type, with tester type 'Simple' and have export PATH=$GRADLE2_HOME/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no test type for build tools. However, there are two alternatives you can implement instead:

1. Use a build job type, run the test, echo a link to the test results and exit using a status
2. Use the new [custom image support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzSSQ.png][1]) to either create your own docker image with gradle (along with anything else) or use an existing  one in docker hub like this one: https://hub.docker.com/_/gradle/